# React - injected component doesn't fit with the parent page DOM correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

I have a page component built with React.js. The page has header, content and a top toolbar.

This is the render of the component page:

```
<Page noSwipeback>
  <Navbar sliding={false}>
    <NavLeft>
      <Link iconIos="f7:menu" iconMd="material:menu" panelOpen="right" />
    </NavLeft>
    <NavTitle sliding>{self.state.title}</NavTitle>
  </Navbar>
  <Toolbar tabbar bottom>
    <Link tabLink="#suggestions" tabLinkActive>{RootScope.t['Suggestions']}</Link>
    <Link tabLink="#soon">{RootScope.t['Soon']}</Link>
    <Link tabLink="#history">{RootScope.t['History']}</Link>
  </Toolbar>
  <Tabs animated>
    <Tab id="suggestions" tabActive>
      <ListOrders />
    </Tab>
    <Tab id="soon">
      <Block>
        Upcoming orders
      </Block>
    </Tab>
    <Tab id="history">
      <Block>
        <p>Tab 2 content</p>
      </Block>
    </Tab>
  </Tabs>
</Page>
```

As you can see, the Navbar component responsibles to header of the page.
Now, I want to bring this Navbar as a separate component, called Header component so instead of this Navbar block it will be only:

```
<Header title="page's title" />
```

And there in the header component it should be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavLeft, NavTitle, Link } from 'framework7-react';

export default class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar sliding={false}>
        <NavLeft>
          <Link iconIos="f7:menu" iconMd="material:menu" 
             panelOpen="right" />
        </NavLeft>
        <NavTitle sliding>{this.props.title}</NavTitle>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

However, when I am doing like so, the Header component is not getting integrated properly with the page and its getting placed in the middle of the page, just as a stranger in the page.

What I have tried to do:

When I am doing the same render of the Header component, but without a React's component, but with a functional rendering, it works - the components resides in the right place it should be.

For example:

```
// Header component:
export default function(self) {
  return (
    <Navbar sliding={false}>
      <NavLeft>
        <Link iconIos="f7:menu" iconMd="material:menu" panelOpen="right" />
      </NavLeft>
      <NavTitle sliding>{self.state.title}</NavTitle>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

// main page:
render() {
 <div>
   {Header(self)} 
   ... rest of the code
 </div>
}
```

So, like this:

```
{Header()}
```

It works. But like this:

```
<Header />
```

It doesn't.

So why when it's rendered using a function it places properly with the parent component and when it's rendered as a React.js component it doesn't?

Comment: Have you imported the correct stylesheets in the react component that you extracted? It probably is a styling issue if you have done everything correctly

Comment: check if there is difference in DOM structure, compare styles too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you are using framework7 for your app. If I had to guess, for `<Page>`, `<Navbar>` probably needs to be a direct child, otherwise it won't be handled correctly.

When you return the navbar from a function, the intermediate `<Header>` tag is not used, so it is again a direct child (this is the difference between your examples).

---

If you refer to the docs: https://framework7.io/docs/navbar.html#fixed-navbar-type

> Fixed navbar is also part of the page but it is always visible on screen not depending on page scroll. In this case it must be a direct child of page and if page has also fixed toolbar then it must be BEFORE the toolbar:

*I know that the above is not for the react version, but I suspect the same is true for react.*

Comment: Yes it's F7. This will probably going to be happened a lot (ruin the direct inheritance) - is there any kind of way to tell React to render the code without the intermediate header, and instead, put the child's render code directly? So `<Header />` tag will not be in actually in the code, just in the SRC code, but after compile, only it's contents will be pulled to the code. Otherwise as I said, it can collide with lots of other CSS rules... related or not related to F7 Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**I have finally found the answer**

I am using Framework7 and in Framework7, every component that is a sub component under the App component is getting automatically (via the F7) to the "main-content" component which are un-fixed elements. If you want to preserve fixed elements like header, you should: `<Header slot="first">`

React doesn't "touch" or interfering any rendering, this is done by the F7.

You can read more about this here:
https://framework7.io/react/page.html#page-slots